# Не создается файл с байт-кодом (.pyc)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Создал проект в PyCharm с одним файлом module1.py:

```
print('Hello module World!')
```

Запускаю на выполнение кнопкой **Run**.

Почему в каталоге проекта не создается файл с байт-кодом module1.pyc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему в каталоге проекта не создается файл с байт-кодом module1.pyc?

Потому что в Питоне 3, такие файлы записываются в `__pycache__` директорию (см. [PEP 3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/)),  которую ваше IDE скорее всего скроет, чтобы не замусоривать вид директории с проектом.

Если вы запускаете модуль, передавая его из командной строки (или если ваше IDE за вас это делает): `python ваш_модуль.py`, то он каждый раз [заново компилируется (`.pyc` не создаётся)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files). Сравните с запуском как `python -mваш_модуль` что импортирует `ваш_модуль` и поэтому `.pyc` файл в `__pycache__` директории может быть записан.

Проверьте также есть ли у вас права на создание поддиректории (от какого пользователя у вас python запускается). Вы можете попробовать [руками скомпилировать модули](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=__pycache__#how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file):

```
>>> import py_compile
>>> py_compile.compile('ваш_модуль.py')
```

Ещё возможен вариант, что создание `.pyc` отключено, к примеру из-за непустой [`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE) переменной окружения или `python -B` опции командной строки.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в настройках Pycharm у вас включено игнорирование этих файлов. Как, например, у меня. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Вот документация по настройке отображения https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/file-types.html.

Не понимаю, зачем они вам нужны. На деплой они не влияют, на систему контроля версий - тоже.

Comment: Мне это нужно для общего понимания работы языка с виртуальной машиной и, в частности, PVM.

Comment: Я так понимаю игнорирование типа файлов .pyc используется только для удобства работы с проектом, т.к. они не предназначены для взаимодействия с человеком. Т.е. просто скрываются из дерева проекта. Но это не влияет на создание таких файлов.

Comment: @АлексейНиколаев да, файлы просто скрыты, они не перестают существовать. просто не захламляют проводник IDE

Comment: Добился, чтобы был создан файл `module1.cpython-35.pyc` в папке `__pycache__`. Но только запустив интерпретатор из командной строки. Буду дальше разбираться как работать с байт-кодом в IDE.

Comment: Кстати один вариантов использования байт-кода - это распространение файлов .pyc вместо .py для усложнения реверс-инжиниринга. It is possible to have a file called "spam.pyc" (or "spam.pyo" when -O is used) without a module "spam.py" in the same module. This can be used to distribute a library of Python code in a form that is moderately hard to reverse engineer.

Comment: @АлексейНиколаев отлично, тогда закрывайте вопрос

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я знаю, файлы *.pyc создаются при импортировании модуля.

module2.py:

```
import module1.py
```

Получим module1.cpython-35.pyc